# How can Google sheets loop multiple cells through sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code to repeat a value(C22) In Google Sheets:

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  let range = e.range;
  if(range.getA1Notation().toLowerCase() === "c22".toLowerCase()) { 
    const rangeValue = range.getValue() 
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets() 
    for(let sheet of sheets) { 
      sheet.getRange(range.getA1Notation()).setValue(rangeValue) 
    }
  }
}
```

But I want exactly the same for C21. What format does the above code need to be?

Comment: Unfortunately, converting code from one language to another is considered out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @braX - which of the stackExchange group is a place for that then? thanks

Comment: I don't know of any. It's a pretty short script tho, so why not use this opportunity to learn how to do each part one by one? It would seem that you can ask for help in Stack Overflow by using the `google-sheets` tag, but do not tag `VBA` or include VBA code in your question. I would start by seeing how to trigger a similar "sheet change" event in google-sheets and put a popup box in it. Once that it working, look into how to do the remaining things.

Comment: @braX - thanks for your answer. It is pretty short and easy, I allowed myself to help the guy... if this somehow forbidden here, let me know and I'll delete my comment. this is the script:
function onEdit(e) {
  let range = e.range;
  if(range.getA1Notation().toLowerCase() === "c22".toLowerCase()){
    const rangeValue = range.getValue()
    const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
      for(let sheet of sheets){
        sheet.getRange(range.getA1Notation()).setValue(rangeValue)
      }
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"c22"` with `"c21"`? What am I missing? Do you need it to run for C21 *and* C22, or just for C21?

Comment: I want both cells to repeat the values. I think I just need this instead: "c22","c21"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```
function onEdit(e) {
const range = e.range.getA1Notation();
const cells = ["C21", "C22"];
  if (cells.includes(range)) {
    e.source.getSheets().forEach(s => {
      if (s.getName() !== e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())
      s.getRange(range).setValue(e.value);
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Gonna try that one tomorrow. I will let you know.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.